# What advantages do capturing the two altars on the new Twisted Treeline map give?

Tags: league-of-legends

There are two [altars](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Altar) in the middle of the jungle on the remade [Twisted Treeline](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Twisted_Treeline) map. What advantages do my team and I get for capturing them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I played custom game to see what is true.

(Do note: These pictures are outdated. Bonus gold is now +3 )
[image: One Altar]
[image: Two Altairs]

You get **3 gold per kill** and **10% buff to AD and AP**.

Also, every time you capture an altar, you gain **80 gold** per player, **240 gold** total for the whole team. This means capturing both altars will net your entire team **480 gold**.

Comment: You also get 80 gold for the team when you capture an altar, so capturing 2 nets you 160g for the team.

Comment: @boiledham per person in team so... 80 gold * 3 teammates. Yes? If it is true please edit my answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You get three extra gold per minion kill. Additionally, holding **both** gives your team a 10% buff to AD and AP.

Capturing an altar makes it uncapturable by the other team for 90 seconds.

Lastly, your team is granted vision of the altar itself.

Sources: [YouTube commentary](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rrLCkkVAsI&feature=plcp) with Janook, [League of Legends Wikia](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Altar)